# Can Windows key be mapped in Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

Using Windows key as Meta is very useful in Emacs, is there the way to do it in Vim?

Answer (score 10):

You definitely can, even in terminal, although you have to use it as a meta key (I found no way to use it on its own).

Edit your .vimrc file with vim. Say you want to remap `Win+q` in normal mode to quit vim.
Simply add your mapping and, when trying to indicate your shortcut, press `Ctrl+V`, then `Win+q`.

This will add something similar to `^X@sq` to your file (but **do not type it directly**, the `^X` is a **special character**).

In the end your line should look like:

```
nnoremap ^X@sq :q<CR>
```

Save and quit, launch vim again, and that's it.

Note: `Ctrl+v` in insert mode inserts followoing key/combination of keys literally. For more info try `:help i_CTRL-V` in vim.

Comment: In an even more distant future, you can map <Win> to Mod4 in xmodmap and use it with abandon.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for answering so ancient question, but solution is really simple: it is impossible to use Win key in the terminal, but it is possible to use it with Gvim. Just pass it as modifier T. For example,

```
:nmap <T-F5> :q<cr>
```

will map Win+F5 to :q command. But it is usable only under *nix.

Comment: what's that on normal vim on Linux? I tried this T stuff, didn't work

Comment: This does not seems to work with the most common gvim frontend (GTK3), it seems that works with the old gvim GTK2 frontend: [link](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/1671)

Comment: Yes. At the time that answer has been written, GTK3 frontend did not yet exist.

Comment: This works for me
:map <T-Right> :tabn<CR>
:map <T-Left> :tabp<CR>

Answer (score 6):

You can use [AutoHotkey to map](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) the windows key to a different key. Only activate the mapping when vim is active:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class GVIM
RWin::Alt  
LWin::Alt  
#IfWinActive  ; This puts subsequent remappings and hotkeys in effect for all windows.
```

Answer (score 5):

None of these answers (including this one) is vim-specific, and the selected answer is Windows-specific. Here's one for *nix running X.

I map my left Win key to the Esc key. This won't work in virtual terminals, but it works in X.

Either:
(1) Append `keysym Super_L = Escape` to `~/.Xmodmap` and execute `xmodmap .Xmodmap`.
|______(1a) ~same as `echo "keysym Super_L = Escape" >> ~/.Xmodmap && xmodmap .Xmodmap` .
(2) Execute `xmodmap -e "keysym Super_L = Escape"` .

If you want it to work in virtual terminals, see [0].

REFERENCES:
[0] http://www.mail-archive.com/screen-users@gnu.org/msg02859.html
[1] http://www.paganini.net/index.cgi/linux/nocaps.html
[2] http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-975229.html

Comment: lots of detail, especially the screen thing appreciated. Although I must admit I generally don't miss the WinKey at all

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, but the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> key combo is a windows only key mapping.  It won't help with vim