# Using Winkeys in Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to use the `winkeys` inside `vim`? I know I can set winkeys to act as <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or other keys, but without it there is a way?

Comment: you need to map `win` key via xmodmap.

Comment: Thanks! My winkeys are mapped as mod4. The output from xmodmap:

mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)

Comment: This has sat idle for a while... if you still need help, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327415/can-windows-key-be-mapped-in-vim/2595589#2595589

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments to the question should have been an answer.  Just reposting them so that people will know this question has been answered:

you need to map win key via xmodmap. – osgx Feb 15 at 19:39

Thanks! My winkeys are mapped as mod4. The output from xmodmap: mod4 Super_L (0x85), Super_R (0x86), Super_L (0xce), Hyper_L (0xcf) – tfmoraes Feb 16 at 18:28

This has sat idle for a while... if you still need help, check out [Can Windows key be mapped in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327415/can-windows-key-be-mapped-in-vim/2595589#2595589) – Dan Fitch Jun 1 at 17:31

Answer (score 1):

Win key is available in GVim as modifier "T".