# What is mod key in Vim, can I assign Win key to Vim mod key?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I know that the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is the default mod key.

But can I change that to the <kbd>Win</kbd> key in Vim since <kbd>Alt</kbd> is already the mod key for my [wmii window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmii)?

Or specifically, can I use the <kbd>Win</kbd> key in Vim for key mapping just like <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>? Like I’d like to do `<Win-J>` just like `<C-J>` in `nnoremap`.

I’ve read the question [Can Windows key be mapped in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327415/can-windows-key-be-mapped-in-vim) But it didn’t answer my doubts. So I came here for help.

PS: I’m using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Are you using a GNU/Linux system?

Comment: @rendon, yes, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Vim doesn't recognize window key, you probably have to do something like this:

1. map window key to a unmapped ctrl key sequence on your OS (e.g. Ctrl + L) (only when vim/your shell is the active window)
2. `nnoremap v echo "hi". Now you can press Win + v

This isn't the best solution since I'm not sure how your OS treats holding the `win` key as multiple dispatches of `Ctrl + l`. Perhaps you need to find out whether you can make it "press and then immediate release" when you press `win` (but hasn't released it)

EDIT:

The solution comes in two parts: Mapping Windows key to a certain sequence (e.g. `ctrl + l`), then in vim, put something like this in your vimrc:

```
inoremap <c-l><c-k> hello
nnoremap <c-l><c-k> :echo("hello")<cr>
```

Now in insert mode pressing `Win + k` should type `hello` for you, and in normal mode, pressing `win + k` should echo "hello".

Comment: You think we can use `contral+2 normal key` like `<C-J-K>`? How to do that?

Comment: `<c-j><c-k>` should work. (Note that in Vim/terminals <c-j> is hardcoded to `Enter` key) You want to use a key that isn't hardcoded like `<c-l>`

Comment: you mean I can map <c-j><c-k> to :echo 'test', and then when I press `Control`,`j`,`k` together, I can got 'test' on my screen?

Comment: yeap pretty much. For normal mode use `nnoremap`, and for insert mode use `inoremap`. For example, if you map `win` to `ctrl + l`, and put `inoremap <c-l><c-k> hello`, you should see that it types `hello` for you in insert mode if you press `win + k`. Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm going to try this now

Comment: Could you modified your answer a bit more clear, so I can accept it? It's vague now somehow.

Comment: Why nnoremap <A-H> :vertical resize -5<cr> doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think your terminal sends `Alt + X` keys to program running in it. If you use the GUI version it should work. (I tried in my GVIM in windows, but you can get it for Ubuntu too)

Answer (score 1):

In my system I use `xmodmap` to make the `Window` key and additional `Ctrl` key, this way I use the `Window` key as my control key (the original `Ctrl` key still works).

Save the following lines in `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
! Make windows Meta key an aditional Control key
remove Control = Control_L Control_R
remove mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add Control = Control_L Super_L
```

Some window managers load this file automatically, if not, use `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.

Comment: But how should I use Win as a different key compare with original control in nmap?

Comment: After this `Win` is a `Ctrl` key, in the mapping refer to it with`<c>`.

Comment: You mean the captalized C？ So it has no difference with the original ctrl in mapping? So I still don't get one more special key for mapping.